# Empty space above AppBar

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

I have built a View using SceneBuilder 10.0 and used the resulting fxml calling it from the mobileapplication class as follows:

```
public class HelloWorld extends MobileApplication {

@Override
public void init() {         
     addViewFactory("GLOBAL", () -> {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            View globalView = null;
            try {
               loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/GLOBAL.fxml")); 
               globalView = (View) loader.load();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return globalView; 
            });             
}

@Override
public void postInit(Scene scene) {
    Swatch.GREY.assignTo(scene);
    ((Stage) scene.getWindow()).getIcons().add(new Image(HelloWorld.class.getResourceAsStream("/icon.png")));
    switchView("GLOBAL");
}
```

I see correctly the view in the emulator/android with its Appbar. The problem is that I have an extra (empty) space above the Appbar of about the same height than the AppBar. Its color is given by the Swatch color. This layer seems to be on top of the view (i.e when I draw something out of the view, it disapears beneath this top layer). 
I have no idea how to get rid of this extra space on top of the AppBar. It seems to be related with the View creation as a FXML file.

Comment: Are you adding an "extra" `AppBar` to the FXML View? The AppBar is added to the underlying container, not to the view. Otherwise, post your FXML file?

Comment: Yes that's it! But the question turns to be where to put the AppBar. At the moment my FXML has as top layer the View. I should have an extra top layer containing AppBar and View ? In the MobileApplication class I am loading the View...

Comment: Or maybe I cannot use the AppBar in SceneView as  underlying MobileApplication AppBar.

Comment: In fact the SceneBuilder template having an appbar in the View is wrong if I understand. It gives the same wrong behavior. The AppBar is a MobileApplication class attribute which is already defined.

Comment: You are totally right. The View shouldn't include an AppBar, so the template is misleading. I'll file an issue to remove it.

Comment: Then how do I do to make appear the AppBar in HelloWorld ? Seems that updateAppBar must be triggerred in View class....

Comment: It is managed by `MobileApplication`, so you don't need to include it. On your views, you can decide what text, buttons you can add. You should use the Gluon plugin for your [IDE](http://docs.gluonhq.com/getting-started/#ide-plugins), and create a project (Gluon -> Gluon Mobile, single view or better Multi-View, Glisten-Afterburner). Also check any of these [samples](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples).

Comment: In all these examples I guess they use the protected updateAppBar method to modify the AppBar in the BasicView class. If I encapsulate the View in the Fxml file using Scenebuilder it is different approach, how can I access updateAppBar? Or the View object in SceneBuilder is useless as it is.

Comment: See the samples, you can always call `MobileApplication.getInstance().getAppBar()`

Comment: Yes it works. but in case of several views, the view must be settled before using switchView in postInit method